# Convertir consulta SQL con un máximo de registros definido a JPQL (con etiqueta @Query)

Tags: java, sql, jpql

Tengo que lograr que una @Query en JPQL arroje un máximo n de registros, tengo entendido que se realiza con el método .setMaxResults(n) pero no se como aplicarlo a mi query la cual es la siguiente:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT dae from DebitosAutomaticosEnvios dae " +
            " where dae.daeReferencia = :referencia " +
            " and dae.daeFechaBaja is null " +
            " and dae.daeEstadoEnvio = :estado ")
    List<DebitosAutomaticosEnvios> findDebitosAutomaticosEnvios(@Param(value = "referencia") String referencia,@Param(value = "estado") String estado);
```

La misma se encarga de almacenar todos los registros que devuelve la consulta en una Lista definida, pero necesito limitarlo a 2000.

Comment: Eso sería en tu consulta usa ```LIMIT 2000``` al final del query, ¿cuantos registros trae tu query ahora?

Comment: LIMIT no es valido para JPQL, por tal motivo se suele utilizar el método .setMaxResults() por lo que estuve investigando.

Comment: Estuve buscando y parece que queires [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153464/spring-data-jpa-custom-query-limit-functionality-not-working)

Comment: Charls muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de verlo. Probé armalo con el nativeQuery = true y agregarle a la query limit 0,2000 pero no me funciona al probarlo con postman. Así que voy a seguir investigando al respecto